# private inheritance in C++ and How to reuse but decorate an operator of base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, decorator

I have a Base class and a "child" class named Something which uses private inheritance for reusing generated code.

```
class Base {
protected:
    Base();
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
    void cool();
    Base& operator=(const Base& other);
};
class Something : private Base {       
public:
     Something();
     void cool(){
           // own stuff
           // call method from base
           Base::cool();
           // own stuff
     } 

     Something& operator=(const Something& other){
           if (this != &other){
              // do own things
```

And now here, between decoration, should be the call of the operator= from base class.
But I am not sure how I should do this in right way. Should I use 
dynamic_cast something like this:

```
              (dynamic_cast<Base>(*this)).operator =(dynamic_cast<Base>(other));
              // do own things
           }
           return *this;
     }

}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Wouldn't `this->Base::operator=(other)` work?

Comment: `Base::operator=(other)`

Answer (score 2):

Despite using `private` inheritance, `Something` is still a `Base`, so it is allowed to directly call the `Base`'s `operator =()` with the passed-in `Something`.

So: `Base::operator =(other);`